# Cached Featured in WFS - can I change default

Tags: qgis, wfs, cache

QGIS currently sets the default to cached download for adding WFS - is it possible anywhere to set the default to non cached mapping (I know you can untick the box, but its for a larger user group)?

Comment: what version of QGIS are you using?